# Run javafx jar as sudo: Unable to open DISPLAY

Tags: java, javafx, jar, sudo, opensuse

I'm building a spring based javafx application which is aimed to run both on Linux and Windows machines.

I've encountered an error, and couldn't find a satisfying solution to the problem.
While trying to run the command `sudo java -jar MS.jar`, I'm getting `InvocationTargetException`:
`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY`

Of course, while executing `java -jar MS.jar` alone, everything works great.

BTW, Running `echo $DISPLAY` in terminal results with ":0"

The software is a javafx UI software, which needs sudo privileges for kernel tasks.

**Machine details:**
**OS**: OpenSuse 42.1
**JAVA version**: "1.8.0_152"

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried any of `gtksudo/gtksu/kdesu`

commands instead of sudo?

If your app is a UI app that should do the trick.

For more info see : https://linux.die.net/man/1/kdesu , http://www.linfo.org/kdesu.html

Answer (score 1):

Quoting an answer from elsewhere that worked for me with javafx as root on Ubuntu ... Maybe this can help someone else. I had the same question as you but for a normal user. Let's say I want to start firefox using the user account foo. I'm logged in as bar:

`[bar@localhost ~]$ sudo -u foo -H firefox`

Sadly that command failed with the same error as in the question (i.e. no protocol specified & cannot open display)

My solution was to simply add the user foo to the list of authorised access to the X server.

```
xhost si:localuser:foo
```

And that was it, I was then able to launch Firefox (and other X application) using sudo and the user foo.